# How can I see in slurm the details all the jobs per user

Tags: slurm

I want to see the details of all jobs of a user.
I know that I can do the following:

```
scontrol show job
```

and then I can see all the details of all the jobs of all the users.
But I am searching for something like this:

```
scontrol show job UserId=Jon
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to use `squeue` with the formatting option to build the command line and pipe that into a shell:

```
squeue --user Jon --format "scontrol show job %j" | sh
```

You can then use all the filtering options of `squeue` like per partition, per state, etc.

Comment: Not sure if this is a difference in slurm versions, but i had to use `%i` instead of `%j`. According to [this link](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html), `%j` is for "job or job step name", while `%i` is for "job or job step id"